# How to remove lines added by default by the C preprocessor to the top of the output?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm trying to use the **C** preprocessor on non-C code, and it works fine except for creating lines like this at the top:

```
# 1 "test.java"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.java"
```

The problem is that these lines aren't valid in Java. Is there any way to get the preprocessor to not write this stuff? I'd prefer not to have to run this through something else to just remove the first 4 lines every time.

Comment: That's the filthiest use of C preprocessor I have ever seen... I wish I thought of it when I was doing Java coding.

Comment: I figured there's no reason C coders should have all the fun when it comes to unreadable code..

Comment: What those lines mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370539/what-is-the-meaning-of-lines-starting-with-a-hash-sign-and-number-like-1-a-c

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're using the gcc preprocessor:

> ```
>    -P  Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the
>        preprocessor.  This might be useful when running the preprocessor
>        on something that is not C code, and will be sent to a program
>        which might be confused by the linemarkers.
> ```

from gcc cpp man page

Comment: Works with mingw too!