# What is the meaning of lines starting with a hash sign and number like '# 1 "a.c"' in the gcc preprocessor output?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I print out the output of C preprocessor by using

```
gcc -E a.c
```

The output contains many lines like

```
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "a.c"
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../include/stdio.h" 1 3
# 19 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../include/stdio.h" 3
# 1 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 1 3
# 31 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 3
       
# 32 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../include/_mingw.h" 3
# 20 "c:\\mingw\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/../../../../include/stdio.h" 2 3
```

I've never seen this kind of syntax in C. Can someone explain what this is doing?

Comment: How to get rid of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946898/how-to-remove-lines-added-by-default-by-the-c-preprocessor-to-the-top-of-the-out

Comment: I tried "gcc -E main.c -o main2.c" with a simple example on my own. I saw that it starts with # 0 "main.c"  (so this refers to line 0), but in the fourth line, the preprocessor stated #1 "main.c".  Why did the preprocessor start in line 0 for me and why did it increment, while the posted example starts at line 1?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

These lines are hints for debugging (where the code following the line actually came from)

```
# line-number "source-file" [flags]
```

Meaning of flags (space separated):

- 1 - Start of a new file
- 2 - Returning to previous file
- 3 - Following text comes from a system header file (#include <> vs #include "")
- 4 - Following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit extern "C" block.

Comment: Official documentation is here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html

Answer (score 50):

These *linemarkers* are mentioned in `man gcc` for `-P` option.

The `-P` option is specifically meant to get rid of these lines for clarity:

```
gcc -E -P source.c
```

See [detailed documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html) (answered before).

Answer (score 2):

Those are line synchronization directives, which allow `gcc` to give correct error messages for errors in `#include`d files.  Other preprocessors (such as `yacc`/`bison`) use the same mechanism to relate C errors to the correct lines in the input `.y` file.

Comment: No, other C code generators like `bison` should emit `#line` preprocessor directives....