# What do gcc preprocessed output lines of form hash sign + digit "# 1" mean?

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

While doing a bug report for CUDA's compiler, I ended up finding this strange behavior with gcc's preprocessing step. I currently use gcc 4.8.2.

### Test file: test.cpp

```
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    assert (a >= 0);
    assert (a
            >= 0);
}
```

### Command

> gcc -E -x c++ -m64 -g -o "test.cpp4.ii" "test.cpp"

### Result file: test.cpp4.ii

```
# 2 "test.cpp" 2

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    ((a >= 0) ? static_cast<void> (0) : __assert_fail ("a >= 0", "test.cpp", 6, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__));
    ((a >= 0) ? static_cast<void> (0) : __assert_fail ("a >= 0",
 "test.cpp"
# 7 "test.cpp" 3 4
    ,
 8
# 7 "test.cpp" 3 4
    , __PRETTY_FUNCTION__))
                 ;
```

The multiline assert seems to be processed differently, leading to these `# 7 "test.cpp" 3 4` lines. What does that mean exactly?

### Update

Apparently, gcc 4.7 gives `# 7 "test.cpp"` (without the last 2 numbers).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of lines starting with a hash sign and number like '# 1 "a.c"' in the gcc preprocessor output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370539/what-is-the-meaning-of-lines-starting-with-a-hash-sign-and-number-like-1-a-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like line markers. As you might have noted, there's no trivial relation between line numbers in the original and preprocessed file. `# 7` in the preprocessed input indicates that the source of next line was line7 in the original (which was named test.cpp).

`3 4` are flags, meaning "macro expansion from system header" and `extern "C"`

[GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html)

Comment: Further info: storing the original line number is useful for the compiler to generate error messages which indicate the line number from the original source

Comment: @MattMcNabb how much does ANSI say anything about it? I think it falls under the `# non-directive` syntax in C99, but then I could not find any semantics for that. Guessing it is just left undefined for implementations to extend at will like GCC did here?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰 in ISO C whitespace is not significant between the `#` and the next token, and `# 7` would be an error; so this is a gcc extension (but that's fine because it only appears in intermediate output; extensions are allowed so long as conforming programs still compile properly)

Comment: @MattMcNabb why does the `# non-directive` syntax not apply here? N1256 6.10 Preprocessing directives.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰 It does. *non-directive* is a grammar spec that's defined as *pp-tokens new-line*, so that is saying that a syntactically valid preprocessor line can start with `#` and end with newline, but `# #` would not be valid.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰: The contents of an `.ii` file are not defined by the standard, as this represents the communication between two phases of the compiler. The `# non-directive` syntax applies only to the _input_ of the first phase.

Comment: @MSalters thanks for confirming it, that is what I had understood as well :-)