# What do the numbers mean in the preprocessed .i files when compiling C with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, c-preprocessor

I am trying to understand the compiling process. We can see the preprocessor intermediate file by using:

```
gcc -E hello.c -o hello.i
```

or

```
cpp hello.c > hello.i
```

I roughly know what the preprocessor does, but I have difficulties understanding the numbers in some of the lines. For example:

```
 # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
 # 1 "<command-line>" 2
 # 1 "hello.c"
 # 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
 # 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
 # 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
 # 374 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
```

The numbers can help debugger to display the line numbers. So my guess for the first column is the line number for column #2 file. But what do the following numbers do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of lines starting with a hash sign and number like '# 1 "a.c"' in the gcc preprocessor output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370539/what-is-the-meaning-of-lines-starting-with-a-hash-sign-and-number-like-1-a-c)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The numbers following the filename are flags:

1:  This indicates the start of a new file.

2:  This indicates returning to a file (after having included another file).

3:  This indicates that the following text comes from a system header file, so certain warnings should be suppressed.

4:  This indicates that the following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit `extern "C"` block.

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html

Comment: Thank you. It is very useful information. I am still trying to understand how these fit into the picture. Could you explain a little bit? I will also continue my research based on your source, see how these flags been interpreted.

Comment: I believe the 1 and 2 flags are meant to give an idea of the nested nature of the include files, so it's apparent who included who.  System headers might contain constructs that are non-standard, so the 3 flag tells the compiler that those constructs are acceptable in that context.  And since header files could be included by either C or C++ source, the 4 flag lets the C++ compiler know not to perform any name mangling.

Comment: Recent versions of gcc can use the "nested nature" to show the succession of include-files where a problem lies.  It's debatable whether that's useful, since the newer versions haven't offered newer type-checking or better analysis, and as a result simply magnify existing small problems.

Comment: At this point I cannot digest much due to lack of knowledge. Will continue my study. Thanks guys.