# How to only process the macros in a C/C++ project without compiling it?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I'm trying to review a C/C++ project which is heavily dealing with macros and function-like macros. What I would like to do is to replace the `define` and function-like macros with their replacement.

For example I have this file:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SUM(a,b,c,d) a+b+c+d
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << SUM(1,2,3,4) << endl;

}
```

And I want to reach to this file:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << 1+2+3+4 << endl;

}
```

Please note that I'm not looking to replace the `#include` lines.

**EDIT:**

`gcc -E` expands the `#define` macros but it will also expand the `#include` macros as well. I DO NOT want the `#include` to be expanded.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Preprocessor output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742822/preprocessor-output)

Comment: @FiddlingBits It won't directly help this case because it will also expand `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019609/any-utility-to-test-expand-c-c-define-macros

Comment: @MikeCAT you could first remove all lines with an include, then "compile" it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run the GCC preprocessor to get the code after macros like #define are expanded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916979/how-do-i-run-the-gcc-preprocessor-to-get-the-code-after-macros-like-define-are)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seeing expanded C macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985403/seeing-expanded-c-macros)

Comment: Just saying, Clangd (e.g. when used with VSCode) is able expand macros on demand. (Not in entire files, but separate macro invocations.)

Comment: The duplicates proposed so far are not correct, because this question asks to expand the macros defined with `#define` but not to process `#include` statements. I do not think GCC has switches for that. One might do it by creating a copy of the source file with `#include` lines altered to suppress them, then using GCC, then restoring the `#include` lines.

Comment: Note that processing the `#define` lines alone will not necessarily produce an equivalent source file—doing macro replacement first, then including included files, then doing macro replacement again may have different results than including included files and doing macro replacement once.

Comment: untested -- I think I used this before -- `gcc -no-stdinc -E ...` *or something similar*

Comment: @pmg `g++ -nostdinc -E ...` worked for me. Looks like it forgets the include path which will result in an include failure (It gives an include error) but it will expand the `#define` macros which is what I wanted. Please write an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used `gcc -nostdinc -E ...` (*or something similar*) before.

*Can't test this at the moment; don't really remember exactly why I used it either*

Answer (score 2):

Use gcc -E to preprocess your source file. Then find the first line of the original source file after all #include and remove all lines before that first line. Then restore #include from the original source file.

Preprocessor marks original source lines for debugger like below so you can easily find the proper original first line after #include.

```
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.c"
```

[What do the numbers mean in the preprocessed .i files when compiling C with gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089168/what-do-the-numbers-mean-in-the-preprocessed-i-files-when-compiling-c-with-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

GCC has the -E flag which makes it output preprocessed source code.

Comment: This is incorrect because `gcc -E` does the full preprocessing, including `#define` and `#include` directives, but the question asks not to process `#include` directives.

Comment: I agree. I've misunderstood. The -E flag might still be useful though if You don't have to go through tones of includes appended in the output. I don't believe there's any ready solution like that for what OP needs.