# Format of GCC-style line directives

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

GCC's [documentation for `#line` directives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html) says that they are like this:

```
#line "myfile.cpp" 123
```

But when I check the output with g++ 5.1 they actually come out like this:

```
# 1 "/a/include/boost/multi_array/extent_range.hpp" 1
# 16 "/a/include/boost/multi_array/extent_range.hpp"
# 1 "/pool2/ap/gcc/5.1.0/include/c++/5.1.0/utility" 1 3
# 58 "/pool2/ap/gcc/5.1.0/include/c++/5.1.0/utility" 3

# 59 "/pool2/ap/gcc/5.1.0/include/c++/5.1.0/utility" 3
# 68 "/pool2/ap/gcc/5.1.0/include/c++/5.1.0/utility" 3
# 1 "/pool2/ap/gcc/5.1.0/include/c++/5.1.0/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h" 1 3
# 194 "/pool2/ap/gcc/5.1.0/include/c++/5.1.0/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h" 3
```

Is there any documentation for this format?

Comment: Yes https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html#Preprocessor-Output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of lines starting with a hash sign and number like '# 1 "a.c"' in the gcc preprocessor output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370539/what-is-the-meaning-of-lines-starting-with-a-hash-sign-and-number-like-1-a-c)

Answer (score 2):

It's documented in a different section: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html

The flags are used to create a stack of includes to improve error output.