Is python's CFFI an adequate tool to parse C definitions from a header file
From python, I want to fetch the details of structures/arrays/enums defined in C headers: the list of defined types, the list and types of struct members, the names and values defined in enums, the size of arrays, etc.
I don't plan to link a C lib in python, but I wanted to use a battle-tested tool to "parse" C definitions so I picked CFFI and tried the following:
Start with a dummy test.h file
typedef struct {

    int a;
    int b[3];
    float c;

} other_struct_T;

typedef struct {

    bool i;
    bool j;
    other_struct_T k;
    
}  main_struct_T;

preprocess it once to be sure to resolve #includes, #defines, etc.
gcc -E -P -xc test.h -o test.preprocessed.h
Then load it with CFFI like this

from pathlib import Path
from cffi import FFI

u = FFI()
txt = Path("test.preprocessed.h").read_text()
u.cdef(txt)
k = u.typeof("main_struct_T")
print(k)
print(k.elements)

which prints <ctype 'main_struct_T'> first.
But fails at the second one (and k seems to contains neither .length, not .item, nor .relements, as one could expect from a ctype instance, as mentioned here)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse_header.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(k.elements)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: elements

What do I miss ? How would you do it differently ?

This is not the right way to use CFFI. The correct approach has been detailed by the creator of the library here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088149/how-do-i-preprocess-a-header-file-with-macros-to-a-non-macro-header-file

cffi simply uses pycparser under the hood. Since you're only interested in parsing C files, you might be happier with just using pycparser.

Self reply here! I made progress!
The CFFI documentation didn't helped much :D
using dir() on objects returned did.
Two options were found, the easiest one is this snippet (more complete answer at the end) :
if k.kind == 'struct' :
    for f in k.fields :
        name, obj = f
        print(name, obj.type, obj.offset)

where k is obtained exactly as explained in the question. This gives:
i <ctype '_Bool'> 0
j <ctype '_Bool'> 1
k <ctype 'other_struct_T'> 4

recursion can be used to dig for other_struct_T
The other option is derived from another question (Using Python cffi for introspection) and lead to this partial snippet:
for k in u._parser._declarations :
    v = u._parser._declarations[k][0]
    if isinstance(v, cffi.model.EnumType) :
        z[v.name] = list() 
        print(v.enumerators, v.enumvalues, v.get_c_name(), v.get_official_name())
        for name, value in zip(v.enumerators, v.enumvalues) :
            z[v.name].append((name, value))
    elif isinstance(v, cffi.model.StructType) :
        print(v.fldnames, v.fldtypes, v.fldquals, v.fldbitsize)
        z[v.name] = list()
        for name, ctype, qual, size in zip(v.fldnames, v.fldtypes, v.fldquals, v.fldbitsize) :
            z[v.name].append((name, ctype, qual, size))

...

classes are different, methods and properties are different... the information inside should be the same, using u._parser._declarations feels ugly though
Update
Here is an (unperfect but functionnal) code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import collections
import inspect

from cc_pathlib import Path

import cffi

class ExtraFace() :
    def __init__(self, h_pth) :
        self.ffi = cffi.FFI()
        self.ffi.cdef(h_pth.read_text())

        self.e_map = dict() # map of types already parsed

    def parse(self, name, recurse=False) :
        e = self.ffi.typeof(name)
        e_set = {e,} # set of types to be parsed
        while e_set :
            e = e_set.pop()
            if e in self.e_map :
                continue
            if e.kind == 'struct' :
                e_set |= self.parse_struct(e)
            if e.kind == 'enum' :
                self.parse_enum(e)

    def parse_struct(self, e) :
        s_map = collections.OrderedDict()
        e_set = set()
        for f in e.fields :
            name, m = f
            if m.type.kind == 'array' :
                s_map[name] = (m.type.item.cname, m.type.length, m.offset)
            else :
                s_map[name] = (m.type.cname, 0, m.offset)
            if m.type.kind != 'primitive' :
                e_set.add(m.type)
        self.e_map[e.cname] = s_map
        return e_set

    def parse_enum(self, e) :
        self.e_map[e.cname] = e.relements

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    u = ExtraFace(Path("test.preprocessed.h"))
    u.parse("main_struct_T")
    Path("e.json").save(u.e_map, verbose=True)


I think the documentation is correct, if sparse?  It states that ctype objects may or may not have these various attributes depending on the kind, and as you found out already, the list of fields of a struct is not in elements but in fields.  There are no details because it's not at all the main goal of cffi, but yes, I guess cffi can be used as just a wrapper around pycparser.

Obviously, digging with ._parser._declarations is depending on undocumented internals which may break in the future (though that is unlikely at this point).
